# Syntastic (vim-plugin) works for c++ and c, but not for Python, html, css

Tags: vim, syntastic, vim-syntastic

I recently got Syntastic (got it by vim-plug, Plug 'vim-syntastic/syntastic') and it works for c++ and c.
Example:
[image: c++ example]
What I used:

> let g:syntastic_cpp_checkers = ['gcc']

And when I use Python or HTML or CSS.

Example(with Python):
[image: Python example] What I used:

> let g:syntastic_python_checkers = ['bandit', 'python']

And same problem is with other languages.

[image: SyntasticInfo for python]

Edit:

```
:SyntasticInfo for python
Syntastic version: 3.9.0-9 (Vim 704, Linux)
Info for filetype: python
Global mode: active
Filetype python is active
The current file will be checked automatically
Available checker: python
Currently enabled checker: python
```

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still cle
ar and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: I hope this helps. Fairly new to the site.